# tinymce opening a new window switches to download dialog in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, tinymce

this pretty much is the thing.

When in tinymce I press anything that is supposed to open a new window, such as color picker or a link dialog, FireFox/Chrome seems to start opening the window and then all of the sudden it opens a standard file download dialog asking if I am sure I want to download the requested html file.

Same Firefox/Chrome with all same plugins is completely able to run all tinymce samples correctly on their example page. So it's not the browser.

The request URL is correct (as shown on LiveHTTPHeaders).

Suprisingly the IE7 does not have this issue.

So I am guessing its something with the behavior of window.open and probably has nothing to do with the tinymce itself.

Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Comment: yeah I kinda figured it after I pressed submit. I guess sometimes it helps to just describe the situation. Thanks anyway!

Comment: confirming: it was mimetypes.
Who has .htm files, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may be sending the page with a **Content-Type** header that the browser does not recognise as something it can display inline - ie, within the browser.  Chances are you meant to send it as `Content-Type: text/html`.
- You may be sending the page with a **Content-Disposition** header that instructs the browser not to display it inline, such as `Content-Disposition: attachment`.